# AngularJs - How to prevent route change on preloaded content

Tags: django-views, angularjs

I'm writing a simple angularJS layer to a django app. On initial page load, the view content is already populated in the ng-view node. When I "manually" execute a route change (via ng-click callback), I do a request to the server to fetch the chromeless html content and overwrite the content of the ng-view node.

My issue is that on initial page load, the route change is executed and thus makes another call back to the server to fetch the same content that was pre-populated in the ng-view node.

I'm not sure if this is just the way Angular works or if it is that django uses trailing slashes and angular does not and thus thinks it is a different route?

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Perhaps canceling the change in $routeChangeStart event?

Thanks! long time SO reader, first time poster.

Comment: Could you give us some code examples? I general I would only do a request to the server if it is triggered manually by encapsulating it into a function of the scope.